# How to restrict rendering of html table on a web page upon selecting entire jqgrid only once

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have jqgrid implemented and I am rendering  a html table upon selecting all check boxes of entire jqgrid. Each time when I select or deselect jqgrid it is rendering html table. Is there a way to restrict the rendering only once? Please help.

Comment: You should include more details which shows what you do. Which version from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) of jqGrid you use? Where is your JavaScript code? jqGrid do nothing which could reload the page. I suppose that your code reloads of the page in some way (submit the form, call of `location.reload()` or in some another way). In any way you should search for the reason of reloading in your JavaScript code first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable say `isEntered` like `var isEntered=false` and in `onSelectAll` function check `isEntered` value, if it's value is `false` then render table and change it's value to `true` like following. Hope this will help you.

**Gloabl varible:**

```
var isEntered=false;
```

**onSelectAll function:**

```
onSelectAll: function (aSel, selected)
{
   if (selected && !isEntered)
   {
      isEntered=true;
      alert('alert will show only once.'); //render your table here          
   }
}
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/HJema/257/)  fiddle may help you. http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/HJema/257/

Comment: Thanks a lot Azim :-)

Comment: Hi Azim, It only works for either onSelectRow or onSelectAll. Please help.

Comment: is there a way that it work twice because I have two tables on the web page on by selecting entire grid and another one by selecting individual row.

Comment: Use another flag for individual row select. See this jsfiddle.net/HJema/260 @Baji